# How to detect obstacles (Tripwire with Laser, IR or similar)

Tags: infrared, laser, detection

Supposing I have a glass sheet 50cm x 30cm, with 10 holes (2 lines x 5 columns), with metal/plastic (i can chose) pins inside it. They can be flush (hidden in the hole) or salient (extending 2mm above, like a flat screw tip).

I'd like to be able to detect which pins are salient. But I can't have anything on top or behind the glass. It must be transparent (except for the pins) and totally free from components except on the borders. I'd have a 5mm clearance above the glass or less (I'd like to keep it really slick).

I considered a few solutions, but would like opinions about them. I believe I could use laser diodes + photo diodes, or IR leds + IR receivers. Any other ideas?

I could have 1 emitter per line and column, but it would have shadowing problems. Or 1 per hole/pin, which would be much more complex and expensive (not to say the alignment or elements).

I thought about using one emitter for each column, slightly off the column axis, with 2 detectors (one for each hole/pin). Not sure if it is possible to find cheap leaser diodes with wider enough angle. But may be possible with IR.

Not sure if IR reflections would be a problem, since I'd have at least 5 emitters.

Avoiding shadowing is a plus, not not absolutely required.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

[image: Representative drawing]

Update: I believe it is possible to do it using cheap IR emitters and receptors. However I'd have to use one pair for each switch:

[image: Updated drawing]

I used red and green colors only to help visualizing the idea. Those are both IR emitters.

Opinions?

Comment: it seems your only feature is a side view of salient position and nothing else. Why , what else can be done to make it visible besides a 3D view. What is the purpose? It seem an IR detector on shadows of remote IR FLoodlight directed to narrow aperture focused on IR shadows is one possibility, thus detecting the incident light off glass or salient shadow.  A recessed IR photo diode can be used if there is no backscatter behind the glass surface.

Comment: How is this an electrical design question? Maybe better suited for another site. Ask a specific question, you'll get better answers

Comment: One per pin isn't much more expensive ( 10 vs 7) and probably much simpler. With care you can aim several lasers at one receiver and drive them one at a time.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, sorry if it wasn't clear enough. Basically, It is a glass sheet with a lot of mechanical switches. Those switches will have a salient pin on the back side of the glass when pressed. My client chose them and wants me to find a cheap and reliable way to detect which switches people stepped on.
I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: @laptop2d, I'm sorry, but the description of this website says I can ask questions about "a specific electronics design problem". That's exactly what I did. Technology selection is absolutely in the scope.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, interesting idea. However, the laser emitters are the expensive part here, not the detector. I considered using only one laser, with diffraction mirrors, but it would be even more expensive.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, the switches are very similar to this one: https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1f4yoNFXXXXbUaXXXq6xXFXXXK/wireless-foot-switch-waterproof-electrical-push-button.jpg
Notice there is a hole for a pin on the bottom of it. The only difference is the chosen one doesn't have the spring exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcus can't you make more optically re-arranged for side rear view blocking with 1 per row.  I have done this on pattern recognition with 5mm LEDs and IRDA detectors recessed 2cm from aperture holes with a unique data pattern on a PIC and detected 8 LEDs in parallel but in TDM patterns so that path blocking was critically dependent on alignment but laser like resolution with cheap parts on board.

In your case emitters on one side IRDA SMD detectors on the other.  You can join your paths in the bottom with ribbon wire crimp wire-to-board connectors or flex ZIF sockets.

[image]
Nylon washer stress relief on thread mounts both sides and 8mm thick glass

Add Blue LEDs for edge lights or strip led for appearance.

> This is a 4D EO problem , a  great challenge for EE's with inside and outside the box thinkers, reduced to 2D , X and time for optical path blocking with low error rate. It can be done with 25 cent 5mm IR LEDs.  A PIC is not needed here, if you have a Johnson Counter and hex Darlingtons and some logic for your interface. Total current consumption may be 50mA~100mA @ 5V.

TDM serial port of gated OR outputs 1000110001 indicates 4 IRDA paths  blocked from 10 footswitch pins.

I successfully built this proof of concept using a 1m path with a wire resistor in its path was enough with care for perfect reception in spite of crosstalk and scattering.  Every path must be analyzed for intensity and attenuation to resolve this design that works to get a binary error free result immune to bright light. PCB alignment is guaranteed but the housing design.

You will need a base to secure the fixture.

I used non-reflective holes and with black heatshrink over the emitters.

### Take 2

[image]

Careful machining is critical and aperture design.

Comment: The LED current  angle of say 10deg is reduced <1 deg to block adjacent emitter paths . The detector path is a bit wider so that scatter can be detected from adjacent channels for AGC in the adjacent time slot by a non blocked path which sets the reference level for each direct path during the horizontal time slot. when they are not emitting. This is a serial process but the parallel Rx's logically OR'd so that Tx channel and Rx channel are Time Div MUx'd in sync.  Thus a Optical TDM MUX parallel path , accurate to 1mm in pin location determined by size of the emitter hole and depth.

Comment: Hi Tony, I believe a Johnson Counter is overkill. A parallel load shift register with serial out would do it. Darlingtons for driving or any buffer indeed would do here.
The TDM arrangement sound like a neat idea, but unfortunately I can't rearrange switches (must be 2 lines).  However your idea could be simplified: 1 emitter and 2 receptors (1 for each switch in the column) for each column. The emitter could be a bit off the column axis. So, 1 emitter per column, 1 detector per switch.

Comment: I could activate one column at a time, eliminating cross talk or bleeding from between columns. Recessed receptors would avoid ambient light interference.
What do you think?
Ps: Sorry about the delay. I'm in the middle of an international business trip.

Comment: @Marcus I don't see how your method could posssibly work with a clear path to only 1 pin if multiple pins extended and no top access

Comment: Hi Tony, check out the drawing I added to the question. That's what I meant.

Comment: 1) I had assumed wrong your picture was a front view and not a plan view so I thought you can't have anything on top . 2) Unless you plan to create < 1 degree optical path and understand how to do this you will get scattering   < I doubt>  So maximize the angle  to reduce scattering and use >=1cm deep recess for both emitters and detectors in <5mm holes. The holes will still cause scattering unless stepped with special material.

Comment: I found some IR lasers with <10deg for about 5 USD each. I believe it would work fine.
However, I wonder if there is a way to make it cheaper.

Comment: There is also a way to ignore the scattering, by making only one emitter active at a time, and reading its corresponding detector.
I believe I could use even wider angle (and cheaper) diodes this way.