# Reducing LED spread via pinhole

Tags: led, infrared, optics

I am making an infrared break beam to detect insects, using an IR emitter LED and detector. The insects fall into a channel and then eventually cross the beam, which travels the length of the channel.

[image]

The insects are quite small, so I want to make the beam as narrow as possible; otherwise an insect could block part of the beam and go undetected. The infrared light from the LED has some spread. I was using a pinhole to screen the light into a beam.

[image]

Through trial and error with 3D printing I found a pinhole profile that works: pinholes of diameter 1.3mm and depth of 3mm on both the emitter and detector can detect an insect with a cross section of 3mm by 1mm.

However, I want to make the beam even smaller, to detect an insect with a cross section of 0.5mm by 0.5mm, and I would like to find a more rigorous way to define a pinhole profile. I am not sure what effect the pinhole diameter and depth have on the size or spread of the beam. I have three questions:

1) How do I choose a pinhole diameter? If a laser goes into a slit, there is diffraction, but is this a problem for an extended source like an LED?

2) How do I choose a pinhole depth? A thicker depth could reduce false readings from IR light reflected from the side of the channel.

3) Do I need pinholes on both the emitter and detector? I had some challenges with IR reflections from walls when the emitter did not have a pinhole, but that might be avoided if the pinhole is made sufficiently deep.

Right now the insect trap is being 3D printed, but eventually it will be manufactured (eg injection molded). I would like to avoid lasers or lenses for size and cost restrictions. I am not interested in focusing the LED, and I understand that I will only be accessing a fraction of the LED's output light.

EDIT: The emitter [(datasheet)](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LTE-302.pdf) and detector [(datasheet)](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LTR-301.pdf) are both lensed to increase their angular spread, so some sort of aperture is necessary to get a narrow beam.

Comment: Diffraction applies to any light, not just laser.

Comment: I had designed a multiple beam system using TDM multiplexed emitters and detectors such that blocking one path at one at one instant allows another path to maintain the AGC, so that a relative change was very sensitive.  All paths were 1m apart with 5mm optos recessed behind 5mm holes and could detect moving  blockage of a 0.5mm wire in the middle.   Something like the answer here for a different problem. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329438/how-to-detect-obstacles-tripwire-with-laser-ir-or-similar/329923?s=1|39.7249#329923  never tried bugs.

Comment: I used  an  IRDA detector and std 10deg  5mm IR emitter with a unique 8 bit code for each emitter with sufficient intensity such that a data error in the corresponding blocked path indicates which path was blocked.  https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/vishay-semiconductor-opto-division/TFBS4711-TR1/751-1066-2-ND/1681200

Comment: Actually the lens on each is designed to reduce the beamwidth from Lambertian (165') to 40'.  But emitters with <20 deg (+/-10) are better.

Comment: what is the channel width if the target is 0.5mm? and maximum light path?

Comment: It's a little complicated. The maximum light path is probably 15-20mm. The channel width is larger than the size of the insect, perhaps 10mm, but it's shaped such that the insect has to cross the beam.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist makes a good point that you do not need complete or even strong blockage to detect an object. You just need a low noise stable signal (over the time the bug takes crossing), and accurate comparison. However, a very narrow beam makes the signal more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The beam is the straight lines directly joining the emitting area to the receiving area.

The emitting area of an unfocused smt led is quite small, maybe 0.2mm square. So it is already the pinhole size that you want. A small led and small photodiode will give you a small beam.

You do not need to cut out the light that goes in other directions, as it simply does not lie on the beam.

Note that using an unfocused LED like this, gives you the same intensity in the (narrow) beam (mW/mm^2), that you get with a focused LED - you are not losing anything. This is counter-intuitive, but true. No lens or mirror is able to get any of the off-beam light back into the (0.2mm) beam - it's impossible.

You want to ensure that your tube is not reflective i.e. matte black, just to reduce the scattered light that reaches the detector and reduces the darkness of a blocked beam

[image]

If the chamber is close to the led, then the beam size is the led emission size. If it is close to the detector, then it is the detector size. You can change the beam size by choosing these.

When you have a choice, you use baffles (perpendicular to the light) not flat walls. The next choice is machining grooves in, which has a 90 degree corner angle.

You can have multiple leds with one photodiode. You can also use an image sensor, area or linear for the photodiode, and sample a big area at once. [Linear sensors](https://dynamax-imaging.com/products/line-scan-product/) are quite simple and low power to read with a micro.

For lowest power consumption VCSEL lasers are also available in SMT, and achieve high beam intensity at lower DC power, as the spread is smaller (eg 8 deg vs 160 deg)

---

You can "remove" the lens by putting a drop of clear epoxy onto the lens, and pressing a microscope cover slip flat onto it (no air bubbles). Any flat, clear sheet will do.

You can align baffles with small holes by threading them all onto a rod or tensioned thread, from sender to receiver, then fixing them in place and removing the rod/thread. [if it is vertical then it does not droop]

When working with infrared you must test your "black" materials (ink, paint, plastic). Carbon-loaded black is black. Red+Blue dyed black is transparent to NIR. Black plastic that lets IR through is common.

Infrared leds can take very high pulse currents. Pulsing with high currents and short pulses, which have a repetition rate such that you cannot miss a bug, will likely give the best system.

Comment: Also, modulate the beam at (say) 40kHz. That way you can apply a high pass filter at the other end for a better signal. So even if the insect only partially blocks the beam it should be easy to detect.

Comment: @ Harry Many LEDs has lenses to broaden the beam, thus the silicon emitter area is not the beam area.

Comment: Unfortunately both the LED and the phototransistor I am using are lensed (added datasheets in question).

Would the baffles/grooves replace the flat walls in the pinhole or the channel?

Comment: @ZachMorris 1) using lenseless (smt 0603) leds will be easier than constructing and aligning tiny pinholes. 2) you can remove the lenses by (a) sand and polish them off b) put a drop of clear epoxy and a cover-slip onto the lens rendering it flat

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Not after my belt sander and polishing wheel have been at them they don't...

Comment: @ZachMorris Since you have bugs, baffles in the bug zone are probably out. You would have a couple of baffles outside the bug zone

Comment: I disagree with your unfocused vs focused  intensity .  There is an optical gain in intensity almost 200% by reducing beam angle 50%,  minus ~10% lens loss. Flat emitter would be Lambertian 165' beam @ 50%.  But dome LED's have parabolic reflectors with lens for focal length.

Comment: @HenryCrun thank you for the picture of the baffles! I think my questions are perhaps better phrased as, how should I space the baffles? Would that be a geometrical, ray tracing exercise?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist No, in the die-die beam ( see my diagram above), there is only a basically constant flux. What the lens does is to put lots of little copies of the die, side by side. Each has the same flux (slightly less due to sin(a)). You are correct that they all total to more power if you either capture them in a bigger sensor (eg 5mm circle, or focus at a single point in space). But here's the rub, they are all beside each other coming out of the lens, never at the same overlapping area in space. If you select any 0.2mm square it only contains 1 copy heading for the receiver.

Comment: I agree you get the same mW/mA with different lenses but that is the total surface area not a 0.5mm path at some distance. so beam angle is important for intensity gain. My experience tells me starting from 120 deg each reduction in angle doubles peak intensity - 10%

Comment: @ZachMorris Thin metal sheet, 1.5-2mm holes (practical size), B1 close to led, B2 25mm from led. This all just mechanics. Just draw my diagram on paper with a ruler for some possible sizes, and decide what size holes are practical to make, and to align, and how big to make the bug cage part. Paper is your friend.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist You are considering the case where multiple parts of the led-lens can illuminate the same part of the sensor. But once you choose the collimated, parallel path, those rays are occuluded. Put another way, a lens does increase the intensity, but only by increasing the effective beam area. [this is true for parallel beam paths. If you can take a focal point, then you can increase the flux through a single die area spot somewhere along the path.] Shame we can't flip to chat and thrash it out, this is abit hard to explain clearly

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist You can try the thought experiment: Can I find a set of mirrors/lens-surfaces that will put 2 parts of the leds emission (say 0 deg and 30 deg) down exactly the same 0.2mm-square tube at the same time? [we can easily put them down separate tubes, that intersect at some point in space]

Comment: My understanding is consistent with correlation of datasheets that for increasing beam angle peak centre intensity is reduced and visa versa the focal angle reduction magnifies the peak intensity.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist These are all measured with an emitter aperture/iris and sensor aperture/iris, that is many times the die size. Thus light refracted at lens surface points far from the LED centre line (>2mm in the case of a 5mm led, and there are more than 400 of these) can hit the sensor. That is the "normal" illumination case (which is what the specs are for). Now once you consider a single 0.2mm co-linear sensing beam this is no longer true. Consider how much good the 5mm lens does, when you put a 0.2mm aperture in front of it: none.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Also of interest is that even when you consider a 5mm led and 5mm sensor with unobstructed path, the SNR of the edge crossing (your ability to resolve edge position) reflects a die width strip of energy, and not the expected  SNR from the unoccluded power hitting the detector. (this why you use a vcsel or eel laser source when it seems an led should do)